# Can i generate build script include environment setup with travis-ci/travis-build?

Tags: travis-ci

I trying some test with travis-ci/travis-build.

Can i made script which include setup environment, like apt-get and start service for addon part in .travis.yml?

when i tried to compile `travis compile` it looks totally ignored addons part.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the compilation of `.travis.yml` happens a phase earlier, when it is decided which image on which infrastructure the build should be run. The command `travis build` from [`travis-ci/travis-build`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build) makes the shell script that runs inside of the container, and there are some parts which it does not take into account because it is handled by another layer.

Comment: Then Can i use other tools/souce opened by TavisCI to generate setup code used in Container?